# Easyocr python import error after changing to exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-import, torchvision, easyocr

I have a python code that uses easyocr to read text from a png image, in pycharm it works fine but when I change it to exe using

```
pyinstaller -F asd.py --collect-all easyocr
```

*this is a solution from github

I cannot import the necessary libraries, how to solve this? There may also be another library that you know to recognize text in an image (it is on a uniform background, so it may be simple), but not the pytesseract type which needs an external application installed on the device to work

code 1:

```
print("import1")
import time
print("import2")
from pynput import keyboard
print("import3")
import easyocr
print("import4")
import threading, datetime, os, gzip, psutil, pyautogui
print("import5")
from PIL import ImageGrab
```

error 1:

```
import1
import2
import3
torchvision\io\image.py:13: UserWarning: Failed to load image Python extension: ''If you don't plan on using image functionality from `torchvision.io`, you can ignore this warning. Otherwise, there might be something wrong with your environment. Did you have `libjpeg` or `libpng` installed before building `torchvision` from source?
torch\_jit_internal.py:857: UserWarning: Unable to retrieve source for @torch.jit._overload function: <function _DenseLayer.forward at 0x0000017E5EDE7F60>.
  warnings.warn(
torch\_jit_internal.py:857: UserWarning: Unable to retrieve source for @torch.jit._overload function: <function _DenseLayer.forward at 0x0000017E5EE08A40>.
  warnings.warn(
Cannot load imports from non-existent stub 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI24122\\skimage\\exposure\\__init__.pyi'
```

code 2:

```
print("import1")
import time
print("import2")
from pynput import keyboard
import libpng, libjpeg
print("import3")
import torchvision.io
print("import4")
import skimage.exposure
print("import5")
import threading, datetime, os, gzip, psutil, pyautogui, easyocr
print("import6")
from PIL import ImageGrab
```

error 2:

```
import1
import2
import3
torchvision\io\image.py:13: UserWarning: Failed to load image Python extension: ''If you don't plan on using image functionality from `torchvision.io`, you can ignore this warning. Otherwise, there might be something wrong with your environment. Did you have `libjpeg` or `libpng` installed before building `torchvision` from source?
torch\_jit_internal.py:857: UserWarning: Unable to retrieve source for @torch.jit._overload function: <function _DenseLayer.forward at 0x0000026148901760>.
  warnings.warn(
torch\_jit_internal.py:857: UserWarning: Unable to retrieve source for @torch.jit._overload function: <function _DenseLayer.forward at 0x0000026148902200>.
  warnings.warn(

import4
Cannot load imports from non-existent stub 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI43802\\skimage\\exposure\\__init__.pyi'
```